# How to add background image for only home page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, background

I have been working on wordpress theme & i want to add background image for only home page so please, help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add to body tag **php if home get class "yourClass"**  and give BG for that class in css

```
<body class="<?php if (is_home()){echo 'yourClass';} ?>">
```

Or give inline background

```
<body <?php if (is_home()){echo 'style="background-image:url(images/yourBG.jpg);"';} ?>>
```

But i prefer first option with *class*

Good luck! :)